Is there some AI software able to filter rss feeds?
I monitor a number of RSS feeds (using Thunderbird as it happens). A considerable fraction of the items are of little or no interest to me but I'm keen to read many of the others.
Is there some AI software that I could adapt to the purpose of screening feeds for items of interest to me? For instance, I have little interest in sport. Items in this general area contain various keywords such as 'team', 'olympics' and so on; however, I'd rather not drop all items that contain the word 'team'.

There is the whole bunch of web services, such as feedrinse.com, siftrss.com and more advanced rss-bridge.org, which would allow you to filter out any feeds with whatever keywords you don't like, thereby retaining only the feeds and keywords of some interest to you.
Though you may still struggle to find any suitable web service to filter your feeds by the language used within it, this is where the AI and language models are still somewhat behind, I suppose. If you ever come across any as such, please let me know - I will apply it to feeds from academia.edu, which often happen to be in 10 multiple languages, some of which I don't read.

Thanks for your answer. I was unaware of these. Still, what I really want is either a service, or a product that I could build on, with the smarts to identify all items associated with, say, the 2024 Olympics. Some of these would be easy to find using keywords, some not.
